# How to send model C# as raw JSON?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, restsharp

I have an data model in C#:

```
  public class RootObjectData
    {
        public Person person { get; set; }
        public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
        public Indicators indicators { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to send this data as raw JSON using RestSharp:

```
public string send(RootObjectData data) {
    var client = new RestClient(RestfulPaths.BASE_URL);
    var request = new RestRequest(RestfulPaths.GET_ANALYS, Method.POST);

    request.AddJsonBody(data);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    var response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

But it send wrong format data.

I fill data like this:

```
RootObjectData bioModel = new RootObjectData();
bioModel.person = new Person();
bioModel.indicators = new Indicators();
bioModel.parameters = new Parameters();
```

If to use POSTman a correct data is (raw JSON):

```
{
  "person": {

  },
  "parameters": {

  },
  "indicators": {

  }
}
```

I try to attain this sending `data` object in C#

Comment: What do you mean by `format data`? What format do you receive at the service? Can you share how are you populating `data` variable?

Comment: Okay, see question please

Comment: You should call `request.AddJsonBody` method by passing `bioModel` to it.

Comment: I did this: `public string send(RootObjectData data) {}` updated

Comment: You also might want to add Content-Type header with value application\json

Comment: Can you share this code?

Comment: I got this error: `Critical error has occurred: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`